# how to display a text in a more readable format in python?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python

and I have **diff** text like this

```xml
   <revision>
-    <count>22</count>
+    <count>33</count>
   </revision>
```

this is config file changes

everywhere that you **+** means line `added`

and everywhere that you see **-** means something `removed`

it is like git .

**the problem** is that above text is not readable .

I want something like this :

```
revision->count : 22 (old) 33 (new)
```

**so** , how can I start for doing that ?

is it needed to use library ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `split` function:

```
a = string.split('<count>')
b, c = a[1], a[3]
final = 'revision->count : {} (old) {} (new)'.format(int(b), int(c))
```